# Remove Dash/Hyphen From Wordpress CustomPosttype Permalink

Tags: permalinks

I want to remove all hyphens/dashes from the Custom Post Type permalink in Wordpress.

For example:

www.website.com/customposttype/post-name/

Becomes

www.website.com/customposttype/postname/

Any advice on how to do this with any functions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. IMHO that is not a good idea, it will not have a good effect on your SEO, and will possibly cause confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use to hook into WordPress's sanitize title hook.

```
function no_dashes($title) {
    return str_replace('-', '', $title);
}
add_filter('sanitize_title', 'no_dashes' , 9999);
```

for particular post type you can use these hook

```
function no_dashes( $slug, $post_ID, $post_status, $post_type ) {

    if( $post_type == "page" ) {
        $slug = str_replace( '-', '', $slug);
    }
    return $slug;
}
add_filter( "wp_unique_post_slug", "no_dashes", 10, 4 );
```